# simplifying perl map and grep

Tags: perl, map-function

I have a requirement to find a particular piece of subtext in all the lines in some set, and I've ended up with this:

```
my @missing = grep { $_ ne '' } map { $1 if m/^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ } @lines;
```

Which works fine. But that grep at the start (to get rid of all the emty lines for when the match doesn't happen) looks horrible.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Just to clarify, here is example input and the output I get without the grep:

```
my @lines = (
    'drivel',
    'prefix: matches: suffix',
    'stuff',
    'prefix: more: suffix'
);

my @selected = map { $1 if m/^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ } @lines;
print "found: $_\n" foreach @selected;
```

Output wanted:

```
found: matches
found: more
```

Output got with the above:

```
found:
found: matches
found:
found: more
```

Comment: What is your input, and what output would you  like to achieve ?  Possibly this can be done with grep or sed alone.

Comment: Just `@missing = map /^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/, @lines` should have the effect you want. But I can't imagine what value in `@lines` would cause your `map` to return an empty string. Can you show a sample of your data please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Returning `()` in a map doesn't add any elements to the output, so you could use a ternary conditional like

```
my @missing = map { m/^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ ? $1 : () } @lines;
```

But `m/...(...).../` already returns a non-empty list on a match and an empty list otherwise, so I think you can just say

```
my @missing = map { m/^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ } @lines;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can handle it all in just `map` by returning empty list when no match is found:

```
my @missing = map { /^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ ? $1 : () } @lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that equivalent to the simpler:

```
my @missing = grep /./, map { $1 if m/^prefix:\s+(.+):\s+suffix$/ } @lines;
```

Comment: Yes, but i wanted  to avoid the grep somehow.